# Calc Mean for hour bucket

Tags: r, datetime, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean Wait.Time for an hour interval of data to capture the time of day, day of week, etc. impacts on the wait time. The head of my data frame is:

```
         Request            Dispatch        Arrival Source Dest Total.Time Wait.Time Travel.Time   path
1 6/11/2021 0:00 2021-06-11 00:00:00 6/11/2021 0:01     99   63         82         0          82  99_63
2 6/11/2021 0:01 2021-06-11 00:01:00 6/11/2021 0:02     23   13         90         0          90  23_13
3 6/11/2021 0:01 2021-06-11 00:01:00 6/11/2021 0:02     35  911         96         0          96 35_911
4 6/11/2021 0:01 2021-06-11 00:01:00 6/11/2021 0:02     23   81         88        24          64  23_81
5 6/11/2021 0:00 2021-06-11 00:00:00 6/11/2021 0:03     89   35        163         1         162  89_35
6 6/11/2021 0:01 2021-06-11 00:01:00 6/11/2021 0:03     36  309         95         1          94 36_309
```

Using lubridate I cut the data into the hour buckets by the following line of code:

```
tube$Dispatch <- mdy_hm(tube$Dispatch)
tube_top3 <- data.frame(table(cut(tube$Dispatch,breaks = "hour")))
names(tube_top3)[1] <- "DateTime"
names(tube_top3)[2] <- "Count"
```

The new head of the data is below. The day3 column is just something I added to make the ggplot better by outlining the Midnight bucket.

```
             DateTime Count day3
1 2021-06-11 00:00:00   302  yes
2 2021-06-11 01:00:00   209   no
3 2021-06-11 02:00:00   189   no
4 2021-06-11 03:00:00   169   no
5 2021-06-11 04:00:00   168   no
6 2021-06-11 05:00:00   234   no
```

What I would like to calauclate is the mean Wait.Time from the original data frame above but for the hour bucket in the cut data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tube_top3 <- tube %>%
  mutate(Dispatch = mdy_hm(Dispatch), 
         hour_break = cut(Dispatch, 'hour')) %>%
  group_by(hour_break) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(), 
            Avg_wait_time = mean(Wait.Time, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much.